# single sign on between Vbulletin and rails applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, single-sign-on, vbulletin

we have a lot of users on a VBulletin forum. now i want write few more apps on rails for the same userbase. Until now all the authentication and session management is being taken care of by VBulletin. What is the best way to provide SSO for my users both onVBulletin and on the rails apps i am writing

---

I am working on single sign-on process with v Bulletin and custom made application. i can logged in at Vb using cookies. i can access all. but when access send "Private Message". it says

"
You have turned off private messages. You may not send private messages until you turn them on by editing your options.
"

is there all permission are set at "datasource" table?..

Thanks
master

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ideally your two sites are subdomains of a common domain (e.g. `forum.example.com` and `rails.example.com`), or share the same domain (`www.example.com`.)  One of the sites would be the primary authenticator, and set a cookie (for `.example.com` in the case of the common parent domain [notice the `.` before `example.com`] or `www.example.com` in the case of the shared domain, so that both applications can access it), where the cookie contains:

- the `user ID`
- a `salt` (random value calculated at login time), and
- a `SHA-2 signature` computed over the triplet (`user ID` + `salt` + a `shared secret key`), where the shared secret key is a secret string known by both sites.

Each site would be able to retrieve the `user ID` and `salt` from the cookie, then use the `shared secret key` (known only by the two applications) to calculate a `SHA-2 signature` that must match the `SHA-2 signature` stored in the cookie.

If the `SHA-2 signatures` match then you can assume that the user is authenticated, otherwise force the user to log in again.

The cookie must be destroyed when logging off.

**The small print**

To protect against session hijacking, all requests made over the two sites should be encrypted over SSL (use https.)  If this is not possible, a hash based on the client's IP address as well as browser type and version (User-agent) should probably be calculated at login time and also be stored in the cookie.  It should be re-checked against the client's IP address and user agent before serving each request.  The hash-based approach is security through obscurity, and can be fooled; moreover, a user accessing the internet from behind a pool of proxies or using [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/) may be kicked out by your system every time a different proxy or exit node (with a different IP address) forwards a request.